# Matlab dictionary with lists as values

Tags: matlab, list, dictionary, cell-array

How to make a Matlab dictionary (I assume its called container.Map(...)) with lists as values? For example, I am trying to convert the following python code to Matlab

```
D = {}
A = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for a,b in zip(A,B):
    if a in D.keys():
        D[a].append(b)
    else:
        D[a] = [b]
```

Comment: Since you say so I've marked as dupe. But I don't see how that answer solves your problem. I would do something [like this](https://tio.run/##JYrBCsIwEETv/Yq9mcBSaKseDIItXv2CkMMScii0qcZsqIj@eozKwMC8eYuNlFzOPRxBN9hgW9JhZ1Q1/NF3bnGH@4I0I7wRkikX@/HGTvRSVbFMspZnCoEeIomDRBh@rQ3CSazyudabl6zOxbSLjzR6F@71ha7C89xaN02Cix6lyvkD)

Comment: My problem was that I was not able to create a map of cell arrays, as it was complaining about type, and I could not find type specifications easily in the docs. After I know how to create the map, the code itself is not hard